# Matching Two Lists Against Eachother

Tags: excel, ex

I have two Lists, List 1 and List 2. Both Lists have two columns, column A and column B, the values in column A(ID) & B(value) correspond with each other. I need to compare these two lists with each-other and find mismatches when they occur.

What I want to do is create a third column, Column C, to say if there is a match or mismatch between these two list, basically stating if the ID in one list has a different value in the other list, example:

A match would be: List 1: column A=tom, column B=5. List 2: column A=tom, column B=5.

A mismatch would be: List 1: column A=tom, column B=5. List 2: column A=tom, column B=2.

The problem is, List 2 has duplicates of column A that contain different corresponding values(column B). My rules would be: if there is ONE match between the two lists(even if a mismatch occurs later in the list) Label it as "MATCH", but if there is no matches for any of the ID's(column A) then label it as "MISMATCH".

Here is the formula I am using, it takes the original ID(column A) from LIST 1 and tries to find a match or mismatch from List 1 and List 2:

=IF(VLOOKUP(A1,A:B,2,FALSE)=VLOOKUP(A1,C:D,2,FALSE),"MATCH","MISMATCH")

I cant simply remove duplicates because they aren't just duplicates, it is a single ID(column A) with multiple values(Column B) in one list, but the formula I am using now will not account for my rule I want to implement and I don't really know where to start or how to make a formula that will understand that if an ID(Column A) contains *one* Match, even if there are other mismatches, to label it as a MATCH. The second problem I have is reporting it in a way were I can have the ID(Column A) and have its state(Match or Mismatch) in one single column without the duplicates, I guess this is tied to the original problem.

Sorry for the long explanation, but I appreciate any help in advance.

Sample Data:

**List1:**

ColumnA | ColumnB

tom | 1

Jon | 2

fred | 3

brad | 4

**List 2:**

Column A | Column B

tom | 1

Jon | 5

Jon | 1

fred | 1

fred | 2

fred | 3

brad | 2

**(Desired Result)List 3:**

ColumnA | ColumnB

tom | MATCH  *because tom has the same values in column B for both lists

Jon | MISMATCH *because jon has different values in column B for both lists for all of the times his ID shows up

fred | MATCH *because he has at least ONE match for Columns B in both lists even though   there are some mismatches, this is where the rule would come into place

brad | MISMATCH *because his value in column B in both lists do not match

Example Screen Shot:
[Screen shot of example data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IT0W.png)

Comment: Maybe include some small sample data that can be pasted into Excel and show what you mean?

Comment: (Also, make sure you're accounting for any leading/trailing spaces.)

Comment: I added the sample data with desired results, I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You could count how many times the match is found with the `COUNTIF()` function.  Then, wrap an `IF` statement around it to say whenever the count is greater than `>` 0, it is a `Match`, otherwise `Mismatch`.  See screenshot below:

Here's the formula I have in cell D4 below: `=IF(COUNTIF(H4:H10,B4&C4)>0,"Yes","No")`

Here's the formula I have in cell H4 below: `=F4&G4`

Hope this helps!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The way to look at this is that it's a match to a list based on two criteria. An easy way to match on multiple criteria is to join (concatenate) the individual criteria values together, and then do the same for the list that you're searching through. The following array formula will do this:

=IFERROR(IF(MATCH(A1&B1,$D$1:$D$7&$E$1:$E$7,0),"MATCH"),"MISMATCH")

NB - my columns A and B contain your List 1, my columns D and E are your List 2.

Enter this formula in C1 and press Ctrl + Shift + Enter (this turns the formula into an array formula), and then drag it down to cell C4.